# How would I ever know if my solo miner found a block?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, cgminer, minerd

I've tried solo mining in two ways:

- using cgminer, ASIC and ckpool
- using minerd connected to my own instance of bitcoin-qt.

Either way, I've never seen any indicator showing that I have mined 0 BTC, let alone > 0. What would it look like if I did beat the odds and mine some BTC?

Answer (score 0):

cgi miner shows

```
A:   The number of Accepted shares
R:   The number of Rejected shares
```

minerd reports yay or boo. see [What do `minerd`s feedback messages (LONGPOLL, yay, boo) mean?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/16859/13866)

Answer (score 0):

You could try solo mining another SHA256 PoW coin with a much lower difficulty factor, just to see what it looks like when your setup does solve a block and it's accepted by the other nodes in the network.

A couple of low difficulty SHA56 PoW coins to try:

- Deutsche eMark (DEM) has a current difficulty factor of 2844931
  (https://github.com/emarkproject addnode=5.9.141.86 )
- FireFly Coin (FFC) has a current difficulty factor of 0.00186396
  (https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=318589.0.
  addnode=91.206.16.214)

Answer (score 0):

When your mining software (e.g., cgminer, minerd) successfully mines a new block or discovers a share, it should display some information indicating your mining success. You would typically see details such as the block height, block reward, and your share of the reward (if using a pool).
ransaction in Your Wallet:** If you are using Bitcoin Core (bitcoin-qt) as your wallet and mining software, a mined block's reward would be added to your wallet as a transaction. You can check your wallet's transaction history to see if any BTC has been successfully mined and added to your balance. Keep in mind that successfully mining a block alone (solo mining) is exceedingly rare, and it could take an incredibly long time to achieve.